How to share data through ViewModels in a WPF MVVM project?
I am learning WPF, and more generally MVVM by doing a simple application.
My MainWindow contains 4 Views.
One is for the main ribbon, which stores some user parameters, and one is for a design sheet, which has a parametrable grid overlay.
Objective :
In the RibbonView, the user can select the grid overlay spacing, and I want that integer data to be sent to RibbonViewModel, then to DesignSheetViewModel, then to be used to refresh the DesignSheetView grid overlay.
RibbonView.xaml : (Definition of a IntegerUpDown)
<UserControl x:Class="GrafcetDesignerWPF.Views.RibbonView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GrafcetDesignerWPF.Views"
         xmlns:Fluent="clr-namespace:Fluent;assembly=Fluent" xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Grid>
    <Fluent:Ribbon Grid.Row="0">
        <Fluent:RibbonTabItem Header="View">
            <Fluent:RibbonGroupBox Header="Group">
                <xctk:IntegerUpDown 
Minimum="5" 
Maximum="50" 
Width="80" 
Increment="5" 
Value="10" />
            </Fluent:RibbonGroupBox>
        </Fluent:RibbonTabItem>
    </Fluent:Ribbon>
</Grid>

RibbonView.xaml.cs : (Binding the View the its ViewModel)
public partial class RibbonView : UserControl
{
    public RibbonView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new RibbonViewModel();
    }
}

DesignSheetView.xaml : (Definition of the grid overlay)
<UserControl x:Class="GrafcetDesignerWPF.Views.DesignSheetView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GrafcetDesignerWPF.Views"
         xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:GrafcetDesignerWPF.Converters"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
         x:Name="DesignSheetControl">
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Canvas x:Name="DesignCanvas" Width="2000" Height="2000">
        <Canvas.Background>
            <DrawingBrush TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,20,20" ViewportUnits="Absolute">
                <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="Transparent">
                        <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                            <Pen Thickness="0.5" Brush="LightGray"/>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            <GeometryGroup>
                                <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="20,0"/>
                                <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,20"/>
                            </GeometryGroup>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            </DrawingBrush>
        </Canvas.Background>
    </Canvas>
</ScrollViewer>

DesignSheetView.xaml.cs :
    public partial class DesignSheetView : UserControl
    {
        public DesignSheetView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new DesignSheetViewModel();
        }
    }

Finally, my ViewModels are defined like this:
    internal class ViewModelBaseClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

internal class RibbonViewModel : ViewModelBaseClass
{

}
internal class DesignSheetViewModel : ViewModelBaseClass
{

}

I know that in the DesignSheetView, I need to replace the fixed values by {Binding nameOfProperty}.
Here is an overview of my app:

The setting of the grid spacing is in the top left corner, and the grid to be refreshed according this parameter is in the center of the app.

I'd made serializable (and likely singleton) model Settings, instance of which both viewmodel have and monitors for changes. Change Settings properties from anywhere and they both update its views.

UserControls would usually not set their own DataContext to a "private" view model instance, i.e. a view model that is not connected to other view models in the application. There could instead be a main view model that holds sub-view models as properties and manages communication between them. When the sub-views are instantiated, their DataContext is assigned a sub-view model from the main view model that is held by the (main) window.

@Clemens Could you drop a quick code example of what it should be ?
I created a MainViewModel as a DataBinding for my MainWindow. In this MainViewModel, I instanciated each sub-view model parameter in the constructor. Now I don't know how to get these instances of sub-view models in the instanciation of my UserControls (sub-views) in the MainWindow...

We don't know how your sub-views are actually instantiated. Assuming that it is done in the MainWindow's XAML, you would have something like <DesignSheetView DataContext="{Binding DesignSheetViewModel}" />, where DesignSheetViewModel is a public property of the main view model that is in the DataContext of the MainWindow.

The MVVM "pattern" (IMO) falls down when dealing with "events" (or at least in the way it is usually used). In this case, you say you want to send a "spacing parameter" "here-and-there". IMO, an "event publisher-subscriber" pattern would be more appropriate and "cleaner"; the single argument being the "spacing parm".

In other words, an "observer" pattern. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/observer-design-pattern

I use Messenger in mvvmlight . It send messages
share data ? I use Static variables.
